# Will invoking angular.bootstrap on "n" multiple DOM nodes, instantiate "n "AngularJS applications?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

Is it correct to say that invoking `angular.bootstrap` will create a new instance of AngularJS, together with a separate digest cycle, root scope, injector and so on?

If so, is it possible to nest such applications (i.e. invoke bootstrap on DOM nodes inside the DOM managed by another AngularJS app)? (I presume no!)

Comment: please remove the `angular-ui-bootstrap` tag as your question has nothing to do with the Angular UI Bootstrap library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will create a new instance of Angular [injector](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector) service, which is responsible for [dependency injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) and controls application life cycle. Consequently, it also creates new instances of the services which are used in the application (including the ones from `ng` module: `$rootScope`, `$compile`, etc).

You may think of it as of a new instance of the application (which is the collection of modules). Angular itself (`angular` object) isn't instantiated.

The thing that differs `angular.bootstrap` from `angular.injector` (the latter just creates a new injector instance) is that it [links an injector instance](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.7/src/Angular.js#L1577) to DOM element by means of `$rootElement` service. This way this element and its children are associated with specific injector instance (it can be acquired with `angular.element(someElement).injector()`).

It is not possible to bootstrap an app on bootstrapped element (or its children), Angular [will protect it](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.7/src/Angular.js#L1566) from being messed up.

However, Angular is not really fool-proof, it can be done by bootstrapping the apps [in reverse](http://plnkr.co/edit/dAOqessCgpNFdSGHCdYN?p=preview):

```
angular.bootstrap(nestedAppElement, ['nestedApp']);
angular.bootstrap(appElement, ['app']);
```

Looks like we finally messed the things up. Nothing prevents `app` from compiling its own directives in `<nested-app-container>`, and it uses its own injector and scope (it is `app` root scope here) to compile them, not scope and injector that belong to current DOM element. And the things will become even more messy if nested app will be re-compiled by some parent app directive.

Bypassing Angular fool-proof bypass for double bootstrapping is quite straightforward. Since Angular uses [inheritedData](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#methods) to get element's injector in hierarchical manner (when `element.data('$injector')` is undefined on bootstrapped element, it is automatically retrieved from parents), it has to be overwritten:

```
angular.module('app').directive('nestedAppContainer', function () {
  return {
    compile: function (element) {
      element.data('$injector', null);
    }
  };
});
```

Now the apps [can be safely bootstrapped in any order](http://plnkr.co/edit/NCVE6bv7R62pWJcI5uxZ?p=preview). But the problem with keeping `app` away from `<nested-app-container>` is still there. It can be solved either with marking `nestedAppContainer` directive as terminal

```
angular.module('app').directive('nestedAppContainer', function () {
  return {
    priority: 100000,
    terminal: true,
    ...
  };
});
```

or by putting nested app into [shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Shadow_DOM)

```
nestedAppContainer = nestedAppContainer.createShadowRoot();
```

which is specifically intended to isolate DOM parts (natively supported by Chrome and polyfilled in other browsers).

---

### TL;DR: the solution to nested apps in Angular

As it is [shown here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ry1RxbOWg5xcwzWhvqz8?p=preview):

```
  <body>
    <div app-dir>
      <nested-app-container></nested-app-container>
    </div>
  </body>
```

and

```
var appElement = document.querySelector('body');

var nestedAppContainer = document.querySelector('nested-app-container');
// nestedAppContainer = nestedAppContainer.createShadowRoot();

var nestedAppElement = angular.element('<nested-app>')[0];
angular.element(nestedAppContainer).append(nestedAppElement);

angular.element(nestedAppElement)
  .append('<div app-dir>(app-dir)</div>')
  .append('<div nested-app-dir>(nested-app-dir)</div>');

angular.element().ready(function () {
  angular.bootstrap(appElement, ['app']);
  angular.bootstrap(nestedAppElement, ['nestedApp']);
});

angular.module('nestedApp', []).directive('nestedAppDir', function () {
  return {
    controller: function ($scope) {
      $scope.app = 'nested app';
    },
    compile: function (element) {
      element.prepend('nested app is "{{ app }}"');
    }
  }
});

angular.module('app', []).directive('appDir', function () {
  return {
    controller: function ($scope) {
      $scope.app = 'app';
    },
    compile: function (element) {
      element.prepend('app is "{{ app }}"');
    }
  }
});

angular.module('app').directive('nestedAppContainer', function () {
  return {
    priority: 100000,
    // 'terminal' is redundant with nestedAppContainer.createShadowRoot()
    terminal: true,
    compile: function (element) {
      // element injector is not 'undefined' anymore,
      // so it won't be inherited from parent elements
      element.data('$injector', null);
    }
  };
});
```

While it may look quite neat, proceed with care. As any other hack that exploits undocumented stuff, this one may conceal adverse side-effects or be broken by new framework release.

There are not so many cases that may be in need of hacks. Most times you have an urge to fight the framework, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: So `angular.injector` can be used to create new injector instances, albeit not linked to the DOM. Does this mean that directive declarations in the DOM will only ever be instantiated using the directives registered with an injector associated with a `$rootElement`? In other words, can you choose to use an injector **not** associated with a DOM node when rendering directives?

Comment: Yes, you can, and you may not be happy with results. Injector's own scope ($rootScope instance and its children) will be used to compile the directive and nested ones (the injectors may end up fighting over the same directive elements). See the updated answer, I've covered that. It should be more constructive now.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you recommend any specific resources that have helped you get this level of understanding of AngularJS?

Comment: Also, rather than pursuing nested AngularJS apps, and using custom injectors for directive rendering, another alternative is to wrap the module object used to configure the injector, such that injector registrations are prefixed with a "namespace". This approach also requires that when using the minification protection syntax `$inject = ['foo']` that the relevant dependencies use the "namespace" prefix. Could this approach be workable?

Comment: If you're not certain that multiple injectors are a must then they are most likely not, it's better stick to more conventional ways. I'm not sure that I understand the last part, can you post a simple example of that?

Comment: After you finished with the manual, check how the things are done in advanced ng extensions, (ui-*, ocLazyLoad) and don't afraid to get dirty and browse often through ng source code (including its own extensions) to figure out how it works. There are not so many articles that can help to get through ng internals, and their authors usually got their skills the hard way.

Answer (score 1):

There's only one instance of Angular. Each app has its own injector though. And since `$rootScope` is a service this means that every app gets its own instance and in turn its own digest cycle.

Bootstrapping involves compiling the DOM, which means nested Nodes would already be compiled when you try to bootstrap them.