# A controller into a controller in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm already using the Angular Bootstrap Calendar and it's working fine. I've added a button to show a modal so I can add a new event using the ui.bootstrap.datepicker.

When the modal pops up, I get the following console message:

```
"Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/ng/areq?p0=DatepickerDemoCtrl&p1=not%20a            1.#QNAN0unction%2C%20got%20undefined
```

Here's a sample of the code I have in my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tpSzPhTbR29wjEIYmmXf) (index.html)

```
<body ng-cloak="" ng-app="demo">
    <div id="demo" ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm" class="row">

    <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="vm.eventCreateClicked(vm.events)">Add new event</button>

    <mwl-calendar> </mwl-calendar>    --> Calendar defined in here      


    <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="modalCreateEventContent.html">
      <div class="modal-body" id="modalEventCreate">
      </div>
    </script>
    </div> <!-- ng-controller -->

</div>        
</body>
```

My Add new event button calls the eventCreateClicked function in demo.js

Comment: two `ng-app` wouldn't work on the same page..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested apps [are doable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32955398/3731501) in Angular but aren't available out of the box and can't be generally recommended. This case isn't an exception. Nested `ng-app` won't do any harm here either, it just will be ignored.

`DatepickerDemoCtrl` belongs to `ui.bootstrap.demo` module (not `app`), therefore `ui.bootstrap.demo` module [should be loaded in `demo` module](http://plnkr.co/edit/cLykBaEoqExUTYqe8hxt?p=preview):

```
angular
  .module('demo', ['mwl.calendar', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngTouch', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap.demo'])
```

Comment: Super, this got rid of the error above. Thanks a lot! I get a `Error: v is undefined` related to `/0.13.1/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js` and AngularJS, but i'm guessing that's another problem.

Comment: Always use unminified versions of libraries during development,  this way the errors make more sense.

Comment: The fix above got rid of the erreor I had, but it seems like it ignores datetimepicker.js when the modal pops up, so I get other errors about the datetimepicker. see [my plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tpSzPhTbR29wjEIYmmXf)

Comment: It is the same plunker as in original post, nothing was fixed there. It is large piece of code, I would suggest to resolve the issues one by one in separate questions.

Comment: Done - [link here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33502123/controller-loads-but-not-executed-again-on-ng-click-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

You have nested ng-app. This is not allowed in AngularJS.
You can have multiple *adjacent* applications on a page, but then you have to bootstrap them explicitly. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18583329/5483079)

Comment: The link is for *adjacent* applications and does not apply to nested apps, this can be misleading.